# something shots down the java script

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest

Please, help me to find a mistake in the function. If I delete the whole code and leave only the alert, it will say "it is working", but with the rest included I cant even get the "it is worknig" text. It looks like the number of document.getElementById rows should be limited...

Here is the java. It is just a huge add-form.

```
function newitem(){

alert("it works");

var hophop = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "php_includes/add_video.php";
var q1 = document.getElementById ("ylink").value;
var q2 = document.getElementById ("ytitle").value;
var q3 = document.getElementById ("ytype").value;
var q4 = document.getElementById ("ytag1").value;
var q5 = document.getElementById ("ytag2").value;
var q6 = document.getElementById ("ytag3").value;
var q7 = document.getElementById ("uname").value;
var q8 = document.getElementById ("ulink").value;
var q9 = document.getElementById ("ytext").value;



var vars = "ylink="+q1+"&ytitle="+q2+"ytype="+q3+"&ytag1="+q4+"&ytag2="+q5+"&ytag3="+q6+"&uname="+q7+"&ulink="+q8+"&ytext="+q9;
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found 2 problems:**

**1)** where is "**?**" after add_video.php

**2)** `ytype` does not have "**&**" prefixed

Comment: omg, im so tired, thank you!